# NodeJS - Why are for loops faster when wrapped in a function than when not wrapped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I did a performance test on for loops with 10 million iterations. One was wrapped in a function, the other was not. Here is the code:

```js
console.time('forLoop')
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++);
console.timeEnd('forLoop')

function forLoop() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++);
}

console.time('forLoopFunc')
forLoop()
console.timeEnd('forLoopFunc')
```

I ran this 5 times, here are the results:

```
forLoop: 7.750ms
forLoopFunc: 5.551ms

forLoop: 7.311ms
forLoopFunc: 5.410ms

forLoop: 7.221ms
forLoopFunc: 5.987ms

forLoop: 7.380ms
forLoopFunc: 5.018ms

forLoop: 7.516ms
forLoopFunc: 5.342ms
```

Why does wrapping it in a function decrease execution time by ~2ms (about a 25% increase in speed)?

Comment: If you compare nothing to nothing you get nothing useful.

Comment: Put the function first, see that now it takes more time.

Comment: Analyzing code that is unrealistic and does not reflect how a real use case would look like, in terms of performance does not provide any meaningful results. Compilers or Just-in-Time compilers are optimized to create best performance for real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to run the function first, you will see that the loop inside the function now takes more time.

This is to do more with how V8 engine that compiles the javascript works rather than just the code.

There is a lot of optimization done under the covers to make the javascript code faster.
One of which is the **optimizing compiler.**

- Since JS compiler is a "JUST IN TIME" compiler, it compiles the first piece of code then moves on to the second piece of code.
- The optimizing compiler finds similar variable declarations etc.. from the previous results. If it finds similar information it uses it else re-compiles.

This image may help you understand how the re-compiler works:
[image]

Image from video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-iiEDtpy6I&t